# How can I change the CSS property value to a value of an element?

Tags: php, jquery, css, background-color

I have the following markup:

```
<tr>
  <th>Colorcode:</th>
  <td class="get-color-1"><?php echo $debtor['CustomFields'['kleurcode1'];?>
    <div class="custom-kleurcode1" style="width:40px; height:40px;></div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".custom-kleurcode1").css("background-color","yellow");
  });
</script>
```

The `td` element with `.get-color-1` class echo's, for example, a colorcode like this: `#000000` and changes every day. I want to give the background of the `div` with class `.custom-kleurcode1` that color with jQuery.

Is it possible to read the inner of the `td` and use it as the `background-color`?

Comment: why jquery why not with inline style and set color by php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the value is placed in to a text node within the DOM you can retrieve its value from the scope of the `.custom-kleurcode1` element by using `this.previousSibling.textContent`. You can provide a function to `css()` which reads the returns the value to be set, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".custom-kleurcode1").css("background-color", function() {
    return this.previousSibling.textContent;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Colorcode:</th>
    <td class="get-color-1">
      <!-- <?php echo $debtor['CustomFields'['kleurcode1'];?> -->
      #CC0000
      <div class="custom-kleurcode1" style="width:40px; height:40px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That being said, if you have access to the colour code in PHP why not just set the colour style inline when generating the HTML on the server side?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Colorcode:</th>
    <td class="get-color-1">
      <div class="custom-kleurcode1" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: <?php echo $debtor['CustomFields'['kleurcode1'];?>"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh i didn't saw that :-/ sorry my bad

Comment: @NullPoiиteя no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could place the color e.g. in a separate attribute of your td:

```
<td class="get-color-1" data-attr-color="<?php echo $debtor['CustomFields'['kleurcode1'];?>">
```

Then take it from there:

```
var colorCode = $(".get-color-1").attr("data-attr-color");
```

And change the background color:

```
$(".custom-kleurcode1").css("background-color", colorCode);
```